# How to repeat "sub headings" in html table?

Tags: html, angularjs

*I have a HTML table with col-span heading and related sub headings. I am not getting the way to repeat sub heading followed by main heading.

below is the code i have been trying..

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Month</th>
        <th colspan="3" ng-repeat = "item in data.items">{{item.name}}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I expect "A,B,C" td can be repeated followed by the "colspan"*

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `rowspan` for the `Month` header. Instead, you need to use `colspan` there and the value passed to it should be the number of subheadings that particular header has.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', ($scope) => {
  $scope.data = {
    items: [
      {name: 'January'},
      {name: 'February'},
      {name: 'March'}
    ]
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="{{data.items.length}}">Month</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="item in data.items">{{item.name}}</th>
      </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: hi thanks, my requirement is little different.

Comment: Could you please explain more in detail? Or provide a mockup of how you want your final table to look?